# FunctionDecl: How do I get the as-written unqualified-id of a function?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-ast-matchers

I have been able to write a Clang AST matcher that gives me `FunctionDecl` instances. However, I am observing cases where `getNameAsString` substitutes as-written template parameter types with `type-parameter-N-M`. For example, in the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    using value_type = T;
    operator const value_type&() const;
};
```

`getNameAsString` returns `operator const type-parameter-0-0&`. What I am looking for is `operator const value_type&`.

How do I get the as-written unqualified-id for a function?